# Wait for 2 API's fired by different components to complete before firing another API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The main navigation of my app needs to call a `loggedInUser` API to allow me to render different links depending on whether or not the user is logged in. This API is also used in many other parts of my app. I am using Redux for state management so once this API has fired I can get the data via the Redux store from any connected component.

I also have a `ContentPage` component which onEnter loads content via the `loadContent` API. `ContentPage` is a container component which is connected to the Redux store.

Finally, I also have an `isFavourite` API which takes the content ID and type (returned from the `loadContent` API) and allows me to toggle a 'favourite' button on the page depending on the response. This API should only be called after both the `loadContent` and `loggedInUser` API's have both fired (I don't need to bother firing the API if the user isn't logged in).

The code below works fine if the `loggedInUser` API completes before the `loadContent` API, but not the other way round. I'm struggling to think of the cleanest way to make it so that the order in which the API's return data has no impact on the logic. If the API's were both fired from the same component then I could do something like this (as I'm using Fetch for API calls)...

```
<Route
  path={'Content/:id'}
  component={ContentPage}
  onEnter={(nextState) => {
    // Needs to be synchronous
    store.dispatch(loadSession(nextState.params.id)).then(() =>
      store.dispatch(getLoggedInUser()),
    );
  }}
/>
```

...but as they are independent I don't know how best to approach.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

import { getLoggedInUser } from './actions/userActions';
import { loadContent } from './actions/contentActions';

import App from './components/App';
import ContentPage from './components/ContentPage';

export const store = configureStore();

export const routes = (
  <Route
    path={'/'}
    component={App}
    onEnter={() => store.dispatch(getLoggedInUser())}
  >
    <Route
      path={'Content/:id'}
      component={ContentPage}
      onEnter={nextState => store.dispatch(loadContent(nextState.params.id))}
    />
  </Route>
);
```

This is a simplified version of my ContentPage component.

```
class ContentPage extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.content.id !== nextProps.content.id) {
      // If the loggedInUser API hasn't yet fired then this if statement will never return true
      if (this.props.loggedInUser.id) {
        // I only want to fire this API if both the loggedInUser API and the loadContent API have both fired
        this.props.actions.isFavourite(nextProps.content.id, nextProps.content.type);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a var called `stagesCompleted = 0` or something, where each stage `+=1` to it on each API call. Then have a conditional `if(stagesCompleted == 2){}` fire your code and reset the `stagesCompleted` var. that way you can add or reduce how many actions are needed before it fires too.

Answer (score 0):

So back in the dark ages I built an ecommerce store with a single Perl cgi script for each page of the site. Each script when run would collect the data it needed (it's "database" was a bunch of files it read/wrote including a tab delimited products list), then it would write out the html for the page and serve it to the browser. I think it's one reason I like React, it does the same, just much more efficiently!

So what's my point? This is how you should think of your react app. It has state possibly consisting of a store such as Redux, and the state held in it's components, and from that state it builds html. If that state changes, then it rebuilds the html accordingly.

So for your example the whole site should be renderable with no session, with a session but no content, with session & content but no favourite. The components should not wait for the content they need. If it's not present then they render `null`, or a loading message, or maybe placeholder data. When the data they rely on changes, then they re-render accordingly.

Think of your site as frames in a movie, each with it's own unique app state. If you were to lay it all out you could have a screenshot for every possible variation in your state, perfectly renderable by your app.